# Make CSS menu responsive and each item certain width

Tags: html, css

I am using this CSS Code for a HTML menu:

```
#CustomerMenu {
    margin-bottom:35px;
}
#CustomerMenu ul {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(243, 111, 37, 5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(243, 111, 37, 5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(243, 111, 37, 5);
}
#CustomerMenu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
#CustomerMenu ul li a {
    font: bold 12px/18px Arial;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
#CustomerMenu ul li a:hover {
    background: #F36F25;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#CustomerMenu ul li:hover > a {
    background-color: #F36F25;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#CustomerMenu ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:999;
    top: 34px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
#CustomerMenu ul li ul li a {
    background: #666666;
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width:100px;
}
#CustomerMenu ul li ul li a:hover {
    background: #F35F25;
}
#CustomerMenu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

i want to make each `<li>` link a certain width whether it be a percentage or fixed

Also, can i make the menu responsive, whats the best jway to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/ko69pyLz/

Comment: Do you know how many menu items there will be? If it is a fixed number, just divide 100% by the number and use a percentage value. `#CustomerMenu li {width: 10%;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use media queries**

i am not adding full code, just showing how you can proceed, there are plenty of tutorials available in online.

```
@media screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:480px), 
screen and (min-device-width:0px) and (max-device-width:480px){

    #CustomerMenu ul li {
        display: block;
    }
    #CustomerMenu ul li a {
        font: bold 24px/36px Arial;
    }
}
```

JSfiddle - resize the browser to atake effect

**http://jsfiddle.net/ko69pyLz/5/**

Answer (score 0):

As the user **Manjunath Siddappa** stated, I'm not adding full code, or in this case, my example *won't be using your code*.

For the sizing part of it, you will need to use media queries, but since you want a mobile nav, you most likely want it to pull up into one large drop down bar, and that's where this comes in..

This code will help you create a mobile nav that can get vertically stacked/hidden, and then uses a `onClick` jQuery function to open and close the options.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qy6a185b/